# What is func_dict?

Tags: python

If I make a simple function in python, it has both `__dict__` and `func_dict` as attributes, both of which start out as empty dictionaries:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 42
... 
>>> foo.__dict__
{}
>>> foo.func_dict
{}
```

If I add an attribute to `foo`, it shows up in both:

```
>>> foo.x = 7
>>> foo.__dict__
{'x': 7}
>>> foo.func_dict
{'x': 7}
```

What is the difference between these attributes? Is there a specific use-case of one over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're aliases for the same underlying dict. You should use `__dict__`, since `func_dict` is gone in Python 3.

Comment: [*"This proposal adds a new dictionary to function objects, called `func_dict` (a.k.a. `__dict__`)."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/)